# new column containing header of another column based on conditionals

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new to python and I feel this is a complex task

From dfa:
I'm trying to return the smallest and second smallest values from a range of columns (dist 1 through to dist 5) and return the name of the column where these values have come from (i.e. "dist_3"), placing this information into 4 new columns. A given distX column will have a mix of numbers and NaN either as string or np.nan.

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['09-03-1988', '10-03-1988', '11-03-1988', '12-03-1988', '13-03-1988'], 
               'dist1': ['NaN',2,'NaN','NaN', 30],
               'dist2': [20, 21, 22, 23, 'NaN'],
               'dist3': [120, 'NaN', 122, 123, 11],
               'dist4': [40, 'NaN', 42, 43, 'NaN'],
               'dist5': ['NaN',1,'NaN','NaN', 70]})
```

Task 1) I want to add two new columns "fir_closest" and "fir_closest_dist".

fir_closest_dist should contain the smallest value from columns dist1 through to dist5 (i.e. 20 for row 1, 11 for row 5).

fir_closest should contain the name of the column from where the value in fir_closest_dist came from (i.e. "dist2 for the first row)

Task 2) Repeat the above but for the second/next smallest value to create two new columns "sec_closest" and "sec_closest_dist"

Output table needs to look like dfb

```
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['09-03-1988', '10-03-1988', '11-03-1988', '12-03-1988', '13-03-1988'], 
               'dist1': ['NaN',2,'NaN','NaN', 30],
               'dist2': [20, 21, 22, 23, 'NaN'],
               'dist3': [120, 'Nan', 122, 123, 11],
               'dist4': [40, 'NaN', 42, 43, 'NaN'],
               'dist5': ['NaN',1,'NaN','NaN', 70],
               'fir_closest': ['dist2','dist5','dist2','dist2', 'dist3'],
               'fir_closest_dist': [20,1,22,23,11],
               'sec_closest': ['dist4','dist1','dist4','dist4', 'dist1'],
               'sec_closest_dist': [40,2,42,43,30]})
```

Please can you show code or explain how best to approach this. What is the name for this method of populating new columns?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, you need to provide reproducible code (text) rather than images.

Comment: Add some data to the post so we can play around with it.

Comment: Minor note: your example DataFrames contain the string 'NaN', which is different from the numpy NaN value `np.nan`. To more accurately mimic missing data, you can run this after creating your existing DFs: `dfa.replace('NaN', np.nan, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may do what you need.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Reproducibility and data generation for example
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 10, size = (5,5))

#Your data
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = [f'dist{j}' for j in range(5)])

# Number of columns
ix = range(df.shape[1])

col_names = df.columns.values

#Find arg of kth smallest
arg_row_min,arg_row_min2,*rest = np.argsort(df.values, axis = 1).T

df['dist_min'] = col_names[arg_row_min]
df['num_min'] = df.values[ix,arg_row_min]


df['dist_min2'] = col_names[arg_row_min2]
df['num_min2'] = df.values[ix,arg_row_min2]
```

Comment: No name for the method.  Apply the method only to your data, so slice out the date or strings.  This should with with NaN because numpy argorts NaN to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DataFrame is named `df`, and you have run `import pandas as pd` and `import numpy as np`:

```
# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2017-04-15', periods=5), 
                   'name': ['Mullion']*5, 
                   'dist1': [pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, 30, 20, 15],
                   'dist2': [40, 30, 20, 15, 16], 
                   'dist3': [101, 100, 98, 72, 11]})
df
        date  dist1  dist2  dist3     name
0 2017-04-15    NaN     40    101  Mullion
1 2017-04-16    NaN     30    100  Mullion
2 2017-04-17   30.0     20     98  Mullion
3 2017-04-18   20.0     15     72  Mullion
4 2017-04-19   15.0     16     11  Mullion

# Select only those columns with numeric data types. In your case, this is
# the same as:
# df_num = df[['dist1', 'dist2', ...]].copy()
df_num = df.select_dtypes(np.number)

# Get the column index of each row's minimum distance. First, fill NaN with
# numpy's infinity placeholder to ensure that NaN distances are never chosen.
idxs = df_num.fillna(np.inf).values.argsort(axis=1)

# The 1st column of idxs (which is idxs[:, 0]) contains the column index of 
# each row's smallest distance. 
# The 2nd column of idxs (which is idxs[:, 1]) contains the column index of 
# each row's second-smallest distance.

# Convert the index of each row's closest distance to a column name.
# (df.columns is a list-like that holds the column names of df.)
df['closest_name'] = df_num.columns[max_idxs[:, 0]]

# Now get the distances themselves by indexing the underlying numpy array
# of values. There may be a more pandas-specific way of doing this, but
# this should be very fast.
df['closest_dist'] = df_num.values[np.arange(len(df_num)), max_idxs[:, 0]]

# Same idea for the second-closest distances.
df['second_closest_name'] = df_num.columns[max_idxs[:, 1]]
df['second_closest_dist'] = df_num.values[np.arange(len(df_num)), max_idxs[:, 1]]

df
        date  dist1  dist2  dist3     name closest_name  closest_dist  \
0 2017-04-15    NaN     40    101  Mullion        dist2          40.0   
1 2017-04-16    NaN     30    100  Mullion        dist2          30.0   
2 2017-04-17   30.0     20     98  Mullion        dist2          20.0   
3 2017-04-18   20.0     15     72  Mullion        dist1          20.0   
4 2017-04-19   15.0     16     11  Mullion        dist3          11.0   

  second_closest_name  second_closest_dist  
0               dist3                101.0  
1               dist3                100.0  
2               dist1                 30.0  
3               dist2                 15.0  
4               dist1                 15.0
```

Comment: # Select only those columns with numeric data types......... this part returns a key error '[Ellipsis] not in index' for the first part that is commented out  and the actual line that is uncommented returns "TypeError: include and exclude must both be non-string sequences"

Comment: Oh, interesting... It might be a pandas version issue (I'm using 0.22.0). The commented line is meant to be manually typed out in full :P Hopefully this works: `df_num = df[['dist1', 'dist2', 'dist3', 'dist4', 'dist5']]`